# Function is not defined on plain object referenced by component in TypeScript with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, undefined

I've got an angular component and plain class.

The plain class has an enum defined on it as follows:

```
export class ShieldRequest {    
    state: ShieldRequest.StateType;    

    stateAsString(): string {
        return ShieldRequest.StateType[+this.state];
    }
}

export module ShieldRequest {
    export enum StateType {
        Untouched = 0,
        Rejected = 1,
        Accepted = 2
    }
}
```

I need my component to be able to reference the state field of this object. But it needs the string representation hence the stateAsString() method.

my component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { ShieldRequest } from './shield-request';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'shield-request',
    templateUrl: 'shield-request.component.html'
})
export class ShieldRequestComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input()
    shieldRequest: ShieldRequest;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    get state(): string {
        return this.shieldRequest.stateAsString(); // throws not defined...
        // return ShieldRequest.StateType[+this.shieldRequest.state]; // works fine!
    }
}
```

As seen in the comments above, the first line of the state property throws an exception that the function is undefined but the 2nd line works fine. Error can be seen below:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/shield-request.component.html:8:52 caused by: this.shieldRequest.stateAsString is not a function
```

I've tried to search online to find why this is occurring but I can't seem to find the relevant information. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

EDIT:
Here is how the ShieldRequest object is instantiated in a service:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Http } from '@angular/http';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
 import 'rxjs/Rx';

 import { ShieldRequest } from './shield-request';

@Injectable()
export class ShieldRequestService {
    private apiUrl: string = 'http://localhost:24576/api/';
    private resourceUrlPart: string = 'request/';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getAllRequests(): Observable<ShieldRequest[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + this.resourceUrlPart).map(response => response.json() as ShieldRequest[]);
    }
}
```

Here is the component that gets and stores the shield requests from the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ShieldRequestService } from './shield-request.service';

import { ShieldRequest } from './shield-request';

@Component({
     moduleId: module.id,
     selector: 'get',
     templateUrl: 'get.component.html'
 })
 export class GetComponent implements OnInit {
     shieldRequests: ShieldRequest[];

     constructor(private shieldRequestService: ShieldRequestService) { }

     ngOnInit() {
         this.shieldRequestService.getAllRequests().subscribe(shieldRequests => this.shieldRequests = shieldRequests);
     }
 }
```

Finally here you can see how the shield-request component is created and the input is passed (this is the get.component.html file):

```
<div *ngIf="!shieldRequests" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="text-center">Loading requests...</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="shieldRequests" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div *ngFor="let shieldRequest of shieldRequests" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-9">
                <shield-request [shieldRequest]="shieldRequest"></shield-request>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the object you are passing through `@Input` is of actual type  `ShieldRequest`. Everything else seems fine

Comment: Yeah, as shown in the comment in the 2nd code block, the 2nd line works fine which accesses the local `ShieldRequest` object passed in via the `@Input`.

Comment: I'm not a TypeScript expert, but your use of the name `ShieldRequest` looks ambiguous. Are you sure that when you import ShieldRequest, you get the class and not the module with the same name in the same file?

Comment: Me either to be honest but it appears that I wouldn't be able to use the instance of the object as I am if this was the case. I would also be unable to use the statically defined enum `StateType` in my code, therefore my only conclusion can be that importing the type imports both the module and class parts of the file.

Comment: I think shieldRequest is not instance of ShieldRequest. Can u show, what is passed input?

Comment: Typescript compiles to javascript, which ignores all the type definitions you specify here. It takes an object you pass and tries to execute the function you call on it. My suspicion is that the object you pass is not the one you think you do. Could you please show how you create an instance of the `shieldRequest` and how you pass it?

Comment: I've added the extra information as requested. Cheers.

Comment: Try instead of export module ShieldRequest with export enum StateType

Answer (score 0):

You have SheildRequest defined both as a module and as a class:

```
export class ShieldRequest

export module ShieldRequest
```

If they are in the same file that's your problem. When you import:

```
import { ShieldRequest } from './shield-request';
```

who knows what you are importing. Even if that's not the case, not a good idea to name two objects with the same name.

Comment: But I can use the enum values and the object definition within the same class. My module is simply to define the static enums which cannot be defined within the class. I'll give this a try and then mark this if it fixes it. Cheers.

Comment: I thought I wasn't technically naming two objects with the same name? One is a module (a static declaration container) while the other is a class (blueprint for an object).

Comment: I get what you are saying, but I think you are getting unexpected behavior by doing that. I could be wrong too.